# Why doesn't this stream work?

Tags: 13.04, rhythmbox

I have strange problem. These streams:
`http://plus-zielona-01.eurozet.pl:8500/`
`http://www.miastomuzyki.pl/n/rmfdance.pls`
`http://zetparty-01.eurozet.pl:8100/listen.pls`
aren't played by Rhythmbox and Totem too. The streams are correct, you can easily check it. I have Ubuntu 13.04 with ubuntu-restricted-extras. With previous version 12.10 and 12.04 there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug, you can check it here: [Bug #1153934](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1153934?comments=all)

The workaround for this is to kill `gvfsd-http` after starting the stream. If it doesn't work, try using `banshee` for ex.

Comment: Good to know, THX a lot!